# Get symbol at address

Tags: gdb

I'm looking for a way to get a symbol that sits in a specific address.
I know that I can use the command "Info symbol [address]". The problem is that I get the nearest symbol and not the correct one. For example, the answer I get is: a + 28 in section....
The oposite way works: print &c gives the address that I use in the "info symbol" command.
I'm using class A that holds structure B that holds variable C and I want that the "info symbol" command will return C and not A + offset.
Is there any way to do it? Maybe there is a script that does the work.

Comment: There is no need to sign your post or put the question tags in the title. Your user card and the question tags appear below the question, and the questions can be sorted and/or searched by tag.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way to get a symbol that sits in a specific address.
>   I'm using class A that holds structure B that holds variable C and I want that the "info symbol" command will return C and not A + offset.

The problem is that there is *no* such symbol. That is, given this code:

```
struct Foo { int x; };
struct Bar { int y; struct Foo xx; };

struct Bar bb;
```

There exists a global symbol `bb`, but there does *not* exist any symbol `bb.xx` in the symbol table.

So you shouldn't be asking "what symbol sits at `&bb.xx`, but "what field of symbol `bb` sits at `&bb.xx`". I don't believe there is an easy way for GDB to answer that.

The best you could do is `maintenance print type bb`, which will print (among other things):

```
nfields 2 0x2877c70
  [0] bitpos 0 bitsize 0 type 0x2877a70 name 'y' (0x287a9ba)
    type node 0x2877a70
    name 'int' (0x287a9a9)
    tagname '<NULL>' (0x0)
    code 0x8 (TYPE_CODE_INT)
    length 4
    ...
  [1] bitpos 32 bitsize 0 type 0x2877570 name 'xx' (0x287a9c6)  << this is the address you want
    type node 0x2877570
    name '<NULL>' (0x0)
    tagname 'Foo' (0x287a98e)
    code 0x3 (TYPE_CODE_STRUCT)
    length 4
    objfile 0x273cc10
    ...
```